# getting the average of values that the user has entered issues with code/logic

Tags: java

this is my task: Prompt the user to enter as many values as they want. The user should enter the sentinel value 99999 to indicate that they are done entering input. Display the average of only the positive values. Completely ignore any negative values when computing the average. Also ignore the 99999 value.

the output I am trying to get is :

```
 Enter a series of values (enter 99999 to quit):
 93 ­4 18 19 ­2 41 17 99999
 The average of the positive values is 37.6
```

my code so far: 
I think I need a loop, but not sure what kind of loop and how to implement it. any ideas?

```
   public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a series of values (type 99999 to   quit)");
    int number = in.nextInt();
    int valuesIn = number++;
    double average = number/ valuesIn;

   if(number == 99999)
   {
       System.exit(-1);
   }
   else
    {
      System.out.println(average);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You need to add your code into a `do while` block so it will continuously ask for the numbers. and you do your result calculation outside of the while, when the user inputs 99999

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply implement a `do-while` loop:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int number, valuesIn;
double average = 0;

do {
    number = in.nextInt();
    if(number > 0 && number != 99999) {
        valuesIn++;
        average += number;
    }
} while(number != 99999)

average /= valuesIn;
```